# Unsuccessful in querying hive table

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, sum, greatest-n-per-group

So I started learning how to use hive but am having trouble with querying the table I made from the dataset at https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports

After I made my table from the 5 most recent .csv files I tried to find: 
1)The 10 distinct countries with the most recoveries 2)What date each of those countries had the most recoveries on and 3)If there were any countries that had more recoveries than active cases.

I've tried a few different ways but the best I've gotten is the list of 10 filled with 3 or 4 countries repeating.

So rather than having something like
UK,
UK,
UK,
UK,
Brazil,
Russia,
...

I want UK, Brazil, Russia, US...

I've tried order by, group by, distinct, but I keep getting errors/not getting desired results. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I've been using Hadoop to create a .sql file containing a query like the one below. I would then run it with hive -f.

`SELECT COUNTRY FROM COVID_19 ORDER BY COVID_19.CONFIRMED DESC LIMIT 10;`

EDIT - The table was created like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE COVID_19(
`FIPS` bigint,
`admin2` string,
`province` string,
`country` string,
`last_update` string,
`lat` double,
`long_` double,
`confirmed` bigint,
`deaths` bigint,
`recovered` bigint,
`active` bigint,
`combined_key` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
*s3 bucket containing the csv files*
```

And as said before, the data in the link was used to make the table. The 5 most recent csv files.

Comment: Hello Morgan, If you can provide schema of the table with sample data it will be helpful to create queries. It is unclear on what all fields you used in table from data sets.

Answer (score 0):

As for question 1), you seem to be looking for aggegation. This gives you the top 10 countries by their total `confirmed`:

```
select country, sum(confirmed) total_confirmed
from covid_19 
group by country 
order by total_confirmed desc
limit 10
```

Note that it is not a good practice on SO to post multiple questions at once. However, here is one approach for question 2). The idea is to filter the dataset with a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*
from covid_19 c
where c.recovered = (select max(recovered) from covid_19 c1 where c1.country = c.country)
```

---

The above assumes that `confirmed` and `recovered` give daily count of cases. If, on the other hand, they represent always incrementing value, then the approaches would be different.

For question 1, we need to use `max()` instead of `sum()`:

```
select country, max(confirmed) max_confirmed
from covid_19 
group by country
order by max_confirmed desc
limit 10
```

For question 2, it is a bit more complicated. Basically, we need `lag()` to get the value of the preceding day. Then we can use `row_number()` or `rank()` to order records by the difference of recoveries, and filter on the top record per country:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        c.*,
        rank() over(partition by country order by recovered - lag_recovered desc) rn
    from (
        select 
            c.*, 
            lag(recovered) over(partition by country order by last_update) lag_recovered
        from covid_19 c
    ) c
) c
where rn = 1
```

Comment: None of these have worked. The answers for question 1 have given me the error Expression not in GROUP BY key 'country' (error 10025) and the answers for question 2 just lists the full table. If it helps, I'm using Hive 2.3.2

Comment: @Mogan_Clarke: I forgot the `group by` clause - that’s a beginner mistake, I don’t know where my mind was at at that time! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find the results I wanted, thank you GMB for reminding me MAX was a thing!

Q1)

```
SELECT COUNTRY, MAX(CONFIRMED) AS MAX_CASES
FROM COVID_19
GROUP BY COUNTRY
SORT BY MAX_CASES DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Q2)

```
SELECT COUNTRY, LAST_UPDATE, MAX(CONFIRMED) AS MAX_DATES
FROM COVID_19
GROUP BY COUNTRY, LAST_UPDATE
SORT BY MAX_DATES DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Guess I was way over complicating this...